# schemagen.exe doesn't skip @XmlTransient annotated class

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

I annotated a XmlAdapter class like so:

```
@XmlTransient
public class DateTimeXmlAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, DateTime> {
```

but schemagen.exe generates

```
<xs:complexType name="xmlAdapter" abstract="true">
    <xs:sequence/>
  </xs:complexType>
```

so does't skip the class, which was what I expected. XmlAdapter indeed is an abstract class that my transient class inherits from. What should i do?

The reason I refer in a field to DateTimeXmlAdapter is:

```
@XmlElement(name="StartDatetime")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateTimeXmlAdapter.class)
protected DateTime startDatetime;
```

which is correct I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've told `schemagen` to generate schema types for everything in your java package, including the `XmlAdapter` subclass. It therefore sees your adaptor class, which is marked as `@XmlTransient`, and therefore doesn't generate a schema type for it. However, it does generate a schema type for `XmlAdapter` itself.

You need to change how you invoke `schemagen` so that your adapter class is excluded from the code generation. The `@XmlTransient` isn't appropriate here, so remove that from the adapter class.